# Looping through json array in php selecting first value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json array returned from a validator thus:

```
{  "email":["Email must not be empty","Email must be valid email"],
   "password":["Password must not contain whitespace"],
   "rpassword":["Rpassword must not be empty"]
}
```

The data was returned from (an my aim is to get the first value "Email must not be empty" knowing well that 'email' must not always be the first object):

```
  $data = json_decode($datas, true);

 //echo $data[0][0]; // this is what was tried!
```

Comment: It creates an assoc array when decoded `echo $data['email'][0]; //outputs "Email must not be empty"`

Comment: no way @WillParky93

Comment: Did you mean to run  `$data = json_decode($datas, true);` rather than `$data = json_encode($datas, true);`? If so; see this: https://3v4l.org/dED87

Comment: YES I mean json_decode($datas, true);

Comment: Ok, so as you can see it's `echo $data['email'][0];` gl and hf on your project

Comment: @WillParky93 sometimes the 'email' will not be availalbe, my program will then want to get "Password must not contain whitespace" from the 'password' object

Comment: You must try yourself :) There's no fun in it if I do it all for you! You can check if email is set with `isset()` or empty with `empty()`. If you come across an issue that you cannot find a solution too even after doing research, then you can post another question.